# A simple question about dot product

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question

Studying a book on space curves, I found a proof where they showed that the dot product between two particular vectors of $ \mathbb {R} ^ 3 $ was constant. I understand that the dot product is always a real number,then Why do they show that it is constant?. Or, has this concept of mine always been wrong? I'm really confused. How can I understand this better?

Comment: Yes, dot product is a real number. Is this dot product of vector fields along a curve, perhaps? Then as you move along the curve, the dot product is a real number that can vary from point to point.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much, by the way, I found this proof studying your book when you prove Lancret's theorem page 16.

Comment: I didn't know a name for that theorem. What you’re talking about shows up immediately at the beginning of section 2, differentiating the dot product of vectors in the Frenet frame.